# What are the minimum requirements to put a HTML file into a .WAR file?

Tags: jakarta-ee, war

I would like to include a HTML file in a .WAR file, to be able to hit it from a browser(in particular through a Websphere Application Server), but I have failed to find the correct syntax and/or structure that i need to follow/be aware of.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "A web module has a specific structure. **The top-level directory of a
>   web module is the document root of the application**. The document root
>   is where JSP pages, client-side classes and archives, and static web
>   resources, such as images, are stored."

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I looking forward trying it :)

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at this Technote

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21508890